# Acceder a los datos de un Json

Tags: java

Quiero usar una api para realizar un conversor de monedas, hice la llamada con el método get, obtuve la respuesta la converti en un String y luego la converti en JSONObject, mi pregunta es como accedo a los valores. Quiero acceder al valor Result, que sería el resultado de la conversión. Dejo el codigo, la info en string la trae sin problemas.

```
try {
        
        URL url = new URL("https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to=GBP&from=JPY&amount=25&apikey=zMdY0XF5LySMaAebxz5tqZimwBPev2t7");
        
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.connect();

        //Check if connect is made
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        // 200 OK
        if (responseCode != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ocurrio un error: " + responseCode);
        } else {

            StringBuilder informationString = new StringBuilder();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                informationString.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            //Close the scanner
            scanner.close();

            System.out.println(informationString);
            
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(informationString);
            System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("result"));
            
            
            
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Esto es lo que trae el la llamada en String.

```
{ "success": true,    "query": {        "from": "JPY",        "to": "GBP",        "amount": 25    },    "info": {        "timestamp": 1689953643,        "rate": 0.005494    },    "date": "2023-07-21",    "result": 0.13735}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Codigo como texto, no como imagenes, o te cierran el post

Comment: Hola. Pulsa en [edit] para poner el código como texto y de paso agrega también como texto el JSON, parece no tener una propiedad llamada `result` o no la estás buscando en el lugar correcto.

Comment: Buenas ya edite el post, espero puedan darme una mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta obtiene un objeto json correcto:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "query": {
        "from": "JPY",
        "to": "GBP",
        "amount": 25
    },
    "info": {
        "timestamp": 1689953643,
        "rate": 0.005494
    },
    "date": "2023-07-21",
    "result": 0.13735
}
```

Para poder obtener el valor de `result` realiza lo siguiente:

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(informationString.toString());
        double result = jsonObject.getDouble("result");
        System.out.println("valor result: " + result);
```

Comment: Buenas, funciono!
Me podes explicar como es el funcionamiento recién estoy empezando con java y me serviría mucho

Comment: Si te refieres a el funcionamiento de como obtener los datos, simplemente debes contemplar que Si el .json inicia con { se considera como objeto Json.
Si el .json inicia con [ es considerado como Arreglo Json, dependiendo de esto determinas usar JSONObject o JSONArray, al obtener un objeto con JSONObjet, puedes acceder a sus valores mediante varios metodos "get" que tiene la clase: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F10042_01/reference-java-api/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, le pegare una leída al link!